# SDL_CreateThread и барьер памяти

Tags: c++, c, многопоточность, sdl2

До запуска дополнительного потока создается семафор, который используется в создаваемом потоке:

```
// Main thread:
SDL_sem* sem = SDL_CreateSemaphore(0);
SDL_CreateThread(...);

...

// Second thread:
SDL_SemWait(sem);
```

Вопрос - могут ли поменяться местами (компилятором/процессором) создание семафора и потока? (и возникнет ошибка при обращении к ещё не созданному семафору в новом потоке).

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, компилятор вызовы функций в разных операторах не переставляет. Может ли (в рамках OutOfOrder) переставить их процессор? Теоретически, наверное  зависит от реализации SDL в конкретной ОС, а практически -- я сильно сомневаюсь, что такое может случится.

Answer (score 3):

Ключевое свойство всех оптимизаций компиляторов придерживающихся стандартов в том, что они не меняют результат вычислений, если в исходном коде нет UB. Исходя из этого можно быть вполне уверенным, что компилятор не переставит местами вызовы функций, покуда не будет точно уверен, что у них нет побочных эффектов (например, для gcc если они не объявлены с `__attribute__(pure)`). Таким образом, если вызов `SDL_CreateSemaphore(0)` идёт до `SDL_CreateThread(...)`, то можно не боятся, что при исполнении они как-то поменяются...

Конечно всегда может представить сферический компилятор в вакууме, который делает всё что ему вздумается, но это уже совсем другая история... Также может быть столь же сферическая библиотека реализующая свои вызовы, как отложенные, но это уже проблема библиотеки, и пользователь об этом беспокоиться не должен... И ни к любой вменяемой реализации SDL, ни к любому вменяемому компилятору это всё не относится...

Comment: Все это никак не помешает второму потоку **не видеть** запись в `sem`.

Comment: @ixSci, в каком смысле?

Comment: Ну вот смотрите: к примеру, поток 1 (П1) записывает в `sem`, эта запись идёт во write-buffer и не доходит до кэша. В этом время, на втором ядре стартует П2, в котором выполняется код из вопроса. При ожидании на семафоре совершенно точно есть барьер, как минимум на чтение. Но если в П1 не было барьера на запись, то никто не гарантирует, что write-buffer будет освобождён и кэш увидит новые данные. Без этого, П2 не увидит этой инициализации. Это всё теория и на практике, скорее всего, барьер на создании потока всё-таки есть. Но если нет, то вышеизложенная ситуация возможна.

Comment: @ixSci, П2 же не как-то магически стартует, а запускается П1. Честно сказать, не знаю как происходит создание потока на уровнях ниже, API ОС, но разве это гипотетически возможно передать управление другому потоку без синхронизации? Например, адрес точки входа должен быть записан в контекст П2 именно из П1, что так или иначе, очевидно, потребует создание барьера...

Comment: Понимаете, здесь, в сущности, нечего обсуждать. У API функции подобные вещи должны быть в документации, если же это не описано, то остаётся только гадать. Я с Вам не спорю, что скорее всего барьер там есть, иначе куча кода была бы просто сломана, другое дело гипотетических ситуаций можно придумать массу, в том числе и таких, когда точка входа и семафор приходят в П2 разными путями. Архитектуры могут быть разными, как железа, так и ОС.